# Stop view pager swipe propagation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-event

I've a view pager with 3 fragments.
Inside one of these I've another view pager.
When i swipe the nested one and arrive to "end", then its "parent container" starts swiping itself. I'd like to prevent child to parent event propagation. Any simple way? Many thanks.